# How To See TCP Transferred Data Size In Wireshark

Tags: http, networking, tcp, wireshark

I am having difficulty about understanding tcp traffic between server working on 8000 port on my pc and my browser. I am trying to display an image in my browser that is hosted on this server. While loading the browser page, I started the wireshark and captured the traffic. My goal is to confirm that the transferred data with tcp is equal to 2621 bytes which is the size of the actual image. 
Here is the traffic:
[image]

Here, I thought that the packet in which the image is transferred is this boxed packet. But its size is 262 bytes and not equal to actual image size. How can figure out in which packets the image is tranferred and how can I see its size? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Its payload size is 186 bytes actually.

Comment: But how can I calculate that 2621 bytes is transferred in total? Because the image is 2621 bytes actually

Comment: You can't, from this dump. The total amount transferred was only the HTTP response header, 186 bytes. *Ergo* this isn't the right dump.

Comment: From which dump I can calculate that?

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler Classic to inspect HTTP/HTTPS traffic to and from browsers.

https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddler-classic